# Accessing textbox in windows.resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox with name = "TextboxA" in a hierarchical template in window.resources. From the C# side, how do I access that particular textbox in the hierarchical data template?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to have a reference to the item which is being templated so you can get that instance of that control, there may be quite a few of them in existence at any point. Then you can get the template and try to [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) (read this!) the element on the templated item:

```
var template = (HierarchicalDataTemplate)FindResource("ResourceKeyOfTemplate");
FrameworkElement templatedParent = /* Needs a reference to the templated parent here */;
var textbox = (TextBox)template.FindName("TextboxA", templatedParent);
```

Comment: Do u mean by the parent template the hierachicalDataTemplate is in? Mine is in a treeview.

Comment: @edelweiss: Templated parent, not parent template. Read the page, there is an example there...